# Not able to read Multipart file using spring controller when file passed via apache httpclient

Tags: apache-commons-httpclient

On my UI page, I am trying to upload one file by setting the enctype="multipart/form-data" and  encoding="multipart/form-data" on my html form.

Able to read the file contents successfully in my server class (servlet) using the org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload APIs.

After that I am trying to pass the file or its contents to another server using the apache commons Httpclient using its muiltpart option, I can verify the contents are being passed to another layer (by checking the request body contents or verifying the request in chrome developer tool)

But on another server layer (which is spring based controller),when trying to read the uploaded file using  to be uploaded via but not getting the contents. Rather it says  "Required MultipartFile parameter 'fileContents' is not present".

Could you please help me out what could be the possible issue for not getting file in Spring controller.

1. Server Class / servlet Implementation for posting the file to different server:

   ```
   HttpMethod httpMethod = new PostMethod(epsURL);

   String contentTypeRequested = request.getContentType();

   httpMethod.setRequestHeader("Content-type", contentTypeRequested);

       if(isMultipart){
   String content = getUploadFileContents(request);
   File file = null;
   try {
       file = new File("fileContents");
       if (!file.exists()) {
           file.createNewFile();
       }
       FileWriter fw;
       fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
       BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
       bw.write(content.toString());
       bw.close();
   } catch (IOException e1) {
       e1.printStackTrace();
   }
   try{
       Part[] parts = {
           new FilePart(file.getName(), file)
       };

       MultipartRequestEntity multipart = new MultipartRequestEntity(parts, httpMethod.getParams());
       ((PostMethod) httpMethod).setRequestEntity(multipart);

   }catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   }
   ```

**2.Spring layer changes inside context-config.xml:**

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"  class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000"/>
    <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="100000"/>
</bean>
```

**3.Spring Controller Implementation:**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/type/details")
public
void getTypeDetails(
        @RequestParam("fileContents") MultipartFile file,
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
/// some business logic here based on file object.
}
```

I am getting the below error:

**Error:**
2014-04-16 16:28:51,638  [http-bio-8080-exec-2] ERROR com.MyControllerImpl - Exception Occured: : org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required MultipartFile parameter '**fileContents**' is not present
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:208)

Comment: I have similar problem. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I find out that if you want to get Multipart file in your controller without its name, you can try something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/type/details")
public
void getTypeDetails( any other parameters,
        MultipartRequest request) {
/// some business logic here based on file object.
}
```

The MiltipartRequest will contain all information about multipart request section.